# On prime factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a prime $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor. Let $N$ be a non hyperfinite finite index subfactor $N$, is $N$ prime factor?

Comment: First, is there a non-hyperfinite factor with an hyperfinite finite index subfactor? Next, what about Proposition 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302082.pdf) of Narutaka Ozawa?

Comment: What is the context for the question? What examples have you tried to look at? For instance, what is the simplest example of a prime ${\rm II}_1$ factor that you know of, and what have you been able to find out about its subfactor theory?

Comment: For example all free group factors are prime @choi. One cannot write it as tensor product of two vN algebbras.

Comment: Yes, I know this result (although I have never looked at its proof). My point, as I have tried to indicate on some of your other questions, is that you may receive a better response to your questions if you provide some of the background knowledge you already have AND indicate what you have already tried to do to resolve the problem. Sometimes, the way to make progress in mathematical research is not just thinking of a question and hoping someone has proved a big theorem that answers it, but to consider special cases and examine how they work